# Crear una rama sin archivos de un repositorio existente.git

Tags: git, github

Quiero crear una rama **sin archivos** para un repositorio existente.

Lo que he hecho, es esto:

- hacer una rama nueva
- borrar todo (menos `.git` y `.gitignore`, o sea los archivos de mi proyecto, no los de control o los que generalos los editores)
- hacer `git add .`
- y luego hacer `commit`

Pero me parece una solución de fuerza bruta.

#### Pregunta

¿Cómo creo una rama sin archivos de un proyecto existente?

> **Bonus:** Mi repositorio está en [github](/questions/tagged/github), ¿existe una forma específica de lograr esto para esta plataforma específica? Si existe, ¿cuál es?

Comment: En realidad dudo mucho que git ofrezca algo que haga exactamente lo que pides, porque iría en contra de la razón de ser de una rama.  En realidad, casi suena como que quieres ignorar por completo lo que contiene el repositorio existente, casi como si en realidad tu deseo es de comenzar un nuevo repositorio, no tanto una nueva rama. Si optas por crear una rama, siempre tendrás algún elemento de "fuerza bruta" para que quede vacía, sin importar el método que emplees.

Comment: Tienes razón. Pero una rama sin _parents_ me parece suficiente por ahora. Voy a editar la pregunta, para agregar un poco de información sobre lo que significa _"sin padres"_. Así la pregunta y la respuesta tendrán más coherencia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existe una opción llamada [`orphan`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout/1.7.3.1) para el comando `git checkout`  para realizar lo que creo que necesitas que en si es:

> Crear una rama sin archivos de un repositorio existente

Su descripción en inglés

> Create a new orphan branch, named `<new_branch>`, started from
>   `<start_point>` and switch to it. The first commit made on this new
>   branch will have no parents and it will be the root of a new history
>   totally disconnected from all the other branches and commits.

Traducción (personal (si usted tiene una mejor no dude en editar mi respuesta) )

> Crea una rama huérfana, llamada `<nueva_rama>`, iniciada desde
>   `<punto_de_inicio>` y la cambia a esta. El primer `commit` hecho en
>   esta nueva rama no tendrá padres y será la raíz de una nueva historia
>   totalmente desconectada de todas las otras ramas y `commits`

Para lo cual en conclusión podrías realizar lo siguiente:

```
// Aquí creamos nuestra rama sin padre, independiente y sin historia
// pero con los archivos 'track' y 'untrack' que tengamos
// actualmente en nuestro directorio 
git checkout --orphan nueva_rama_independiente_de_todas_las_otras
```

(Lo anterior es gracias a la aclaración del usuario [sstan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18951/sstan) )

```
// Como los archivos seguirán presentes después de crear la rama
// procedemos a eliminar todos los archivos que han sido y/o estado
// 'track' y 'untrack'
git rm --cached -rf .
```

(Lo anterior es gracias al consejo (muy útil y verdadero por cierto) del usuario [Jhd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/524/jhd) )

Nótese que no es necesario usar la opción `-b` ya que al usar `--orphan` se pasará de la rama actual a la creada cómo se puede leer en la descripción de esta opción.

Comment: Nota que la rama seguirá teniendo archivos, solo que no tendrá historial. Todavía será necesario remover manualmente los archivos usando este método.

Comment: @sstan Eso es cierto, pero sigue siendo la manera más limpia de hacer lo que creo el autor quiere, que es un rama completamente vacía e independiente de las otras

Comment: Independiente sí, pero vacía no. Depende de lo que quiere en realidad Toledano. Me dio la impresión que quiere que la rama quede vacía de una vez sin tener que borrar nada manualmente, aunque en realidad no creo que eso se pueda evitar.

Comment: Exacto, es como dice @sstan, crear una rama vacía. Voy a intentar lo que dice Jorius, en este momento.

Comment: @Jorius en vez de hacer `git rm -rf .` seria mejor hacer un `git rm --cached -r .` todo quedaria de la siguiente forma entonces

`git checkout --orphan <nombre rama>`
`git rm --cached -r .`

Comment: He editado mi pregunta añadiendo la aclaración de @sstan (gracias por aclarar y corregir) y el consejo de Jhd (el cual tenía bastante razón)

Answer (score 0):

apenas que hagas otra rama aparte del máster y develop sin nada para que no te afecte lo que tengas en productivo y desarrollo.
y de esa misma rama que hagas eliminas todo y comiteas

así apenas dejas intacto las ramas importantes

Comment: Gracias José, realmente eso es lo que hago actualmente, pero mira la respuesta de @Jorius, parece que hay una opción para lo que busco.

Comment: eso si igual la rama que hagas la puedes dejar vacía desde el repositorio

Comment: @JoseClementePulidoRodriguez esa rama no tendría archivos pero sí arrastraría toda la historia de commits desde su rama de origen. La gracia de `orphan` es que se elimina también la historia.